# What is the difference between ListItemType.AlternatingItem and ListItemType.Item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know that what is the difference between `ListItemType.AlternatingItem` and `ListItemType.Item` in C#?

I know about `ListItemType.Item` but I want to know about `ListItemType.AlternatingItem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ListItemType.AlternatingItem

represents an even row. When You are working with even row thwn use this option

> ListItemType.Item

represents all the row. When You are working with all row thwn use this option

like if you set the color of all the row then use

> listitem

if you like to change the color of even row then use

> alternatingitem

follow this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`ListItemType.Item` and `ListItemType.AlternatingItem` are both members of the [ListItemType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
They both represent types of items in controls such as `DataGrid`, `DataList` and `Repeater`. `AlternatingItem` represents an item created by the `AlternatingItemTemplate`. This is done so you can distinguish between an item created using the `ItemTamplate` and an item created using the `AlternatingItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

In DataGrid we can check for both types, `ListItemType.Item`  represents a **normal row**,

while `ListItemType.AlternatingItem` represents an **even row**.

Comment: This might be true, but it does not explain why both exist. It's not just a matter of even or odd rows. They are created by different tags in the `DataGrid` markup.

Answer (score 0):

As An Example We Have 5 Diffrent Types Of Templates in Repeater...
`ItemTemplate` ,`AlternatingItemTemplate` ,`SeparatorTemplate` ,`HeaderTemplate` and `FooterTemplate` .
So When We Searching For An Item In Repeater It Must Be One Of These Five Types...
Items That's Declared Inside Of `ItemTemplate` Tag Their `ListItemType` Are `Item` And Items That's Declared Inside Of `AlternatingItemTemplate` Tag Their `ListItemType` Are `AlternatingItem` .